# How do I Calculate the Average using the CalculateButton with following code for a KDRCalculator Program

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, while-loop

In the following code I don't know how to find the average using the Calculate Button. I have managed to read the text in through Text fields for the values but i don't know how to make the program calculate the average and print it in the textfield once the Calculate Button has been clicked.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class KdrCalGui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /**
         * Creates new form KdrCalGui
         */
        public KdrCalGui() {
            initComponents();
            double kills;
            double deaths;
            double subtotal;
            double roundnumber;
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            KillsValue = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            KillsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            DeathsValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            DeathsLabel = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            CalculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            Display = new javax.swing.JTextField();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            KillsValue.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    KillsValueActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            KillsLabel.setText("Kills");

            DeathsValue.setText("Deaths");

            DeathsLabel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    DeathsLabelActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            CalculateButton.setText("Calculate");
            CalculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    CalculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jLabel3.setText("Your KDR");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                        .addComponent(CalculateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 86, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(DeathsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(DeathsValue)
                        .addComponent(KillsValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(KillsLabel))
                    .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                        .addComponent(Display, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {DeathsLabel, KillsValue});

            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(KillsLabel)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(KillsValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(DeathsValue)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(DeathsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(Display)))
                    .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                    .addComponent(CalculateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void DeathsLabelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            DeathsLabel.setText(DeathsLabel.getText());
            double deaths;
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
            deaths=sc.nextInt(); 
        }                                           

        private void KillsValueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
           KillsLabel.setText(KillsLabel.getText());
           double kills;
           Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
           kills=sc.nextInt();

        }
```

THIS IS THE CALCULATE BUTTON.

```
        private void CalculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                


        }                                               

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KdrCalGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KdrCalGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KdrCalGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KdrCalGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new KdrCalGui().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton CalculateButton;
        private javax.swing.JTextField DeathsLabel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel DeathsValue;
        private javax.swing.JTextField Display;
        private javax.swing.JLabel KillsLabel;
        private javax.swing.JTextField KillsValue;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: You have tagged this Javascript but it appears to be Java.

Comment: Write a pseudo-code (or just a list of actions) that `CalculateButtonActionPerformed()` method should perform.

Answer (score 0):

```
CalculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    if (evt.getSource() == CalculateButton) {
                       // not sure what exactly you're trying to average
                       // but if it's the kills and deaths value, then...
                       int k = Integer.parseInt(KillsValue.getText());
                       int d = Integer.parseInt(DeathsValue.getText());
                       Display.setText((k+d)/2);
                       // think about adding exception handling in case they enter a noninteger
                       // also you switched the names of the TextField and Label in the initComponents()
                    }
                }
            });
```